# Why php does not complain when referencing a non existing variable?

Tags: php, reference

I was wondering why php does not complain when we reference a non existing variable (being it a plain variable or array), is this just the way it is, or there is something else I am missing?
For example this code

```
<?php
$t = &$r["er"];
var_dump($r);
?>
```

throws no warning about a non existing variable.

Besides that the `var_dump` show this:

```
array(1) { ["er"]=> &NULL }
```

that `&NULL` is something I didn't really expected, I thought I would get a plain `NULL`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Referencing an undeclared variable automatically defines its name in that scope.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Wrong. See my answer and/or run the code to convince yourself. The & makes all the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If memory of the PHP interpreter reference var allocation serves me right, PHP will create a null element in the hash table with a key like the one you sent and reference it. This is visible by running the following test:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$arr = [];
$arrS = null;
$v = memory_get_peak_usage();
for ($i = 0; $i < 150; $i++) {
    $arrS = &$arr[rand()];
}
$v = memory_get_peak_usage() - $v;
echo $v;
```

Until the default heap size, PHP will return exactly an extra 0 memory used - as it is still allocating already "prepared" array items (PHP keeps a few extra hash table elements empty but allocated for performance purposes). You can see this by setting it from 0 to 16 (which is the heap size!).

When you get over 16, PHP will have to allocate extra items, and will do so on i=17, i=18 etc..., creating null items in order to reference them.

P.S: contrary to what people said, this does **NOT** throw an error, warning or notice. Recalling an empty item without reference would - referencing an inexistent item does not. Big big BIG difference.

Comment: Good answer! +1. I haven't recognized the `&` operator

Comment: You put a very impressive piece of code there, for $i<11 $v echoes zero, very good to learn about heap, default size etc.
The last line in your answer says it all, I know now that this "&" will result in an allocation. 
This allocation (for example here: echo &$var;) comes before echo, this is why php does not complain, because
it echoes something that exists (was created just a step before)! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

> throws no warning about a non existing variable.

This is how references work. `$a = &$b;` creates `$b`  if it does not exist yet, "for future reference", if you will. It's the same as in parameters that are passed by reference. Maybe this looks familiar to you:

```
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Here the third parameter is a reference parameter, thus `$matches` does not have to exist at time of the method invocation, but it will be created.

> that &NULL is something I didn't really expected, I thought I would get a plain NULL.

Why didn't you expect it? `$r['er']` is a reference "to/from" `$t`. Note that references are not pointers, `$r['er']` and `$t` are equal references to the same value, there is no direction from one to the other (hence the quotation marks in the last sentence).

Comment: +1 This is an excellent answer Sir! Especially when you mention "preg_match" and "there is no direction", this very information about direction is something I was missing and it already helped me understand things in depth. Unfortunately I can accept one answer, it was impossible for me to choose both answers are more than accepted, I had to do echo rand(1,2); in order to chose, hope I am not punished for that! Thank you very much! That "direction" thing was so good to learn!