# Is not set variable created if we pass by reference?

Tags: php, reference

```
    $rn = &$vvv;
    echo $vvv;
```

It gives no error. But this, of course, does:

```
    echo $vvv;
```

`Notice (8): Undefined variable: vvv`. Why? Is variable created after we use by reference? That's really strange.

Comment: Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used. Echo is a language construct and therefore php cannot recognize the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much yes - variable is created then
When you want to get reference to object, PHP will do everything to give you that reference.

It simply can't do reference to non-existing variable so it's "setting" `NULL` first and gives you reference to variable

but what's interesting: `isset($vvv)` would return correctly false :)

more info: [Why php does not complain when referencing a non existing variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852981/why-php-does-not-complain-when-referencing-a-non-existing-variable)